# VBScript LDAP query to return mailserver property

Tags: windows, vbscript, ldap

Using the command line tool, ldapquery, the command is this:

```
ldapsearch -h myldapserver uid=myloginname mailserver
```

That returns a line like this:

```
mailserver=CN=mymailserver/OU=xxx/O=xxxx
```

I've tried every variation I can think of using VBS and I can query and get results returned from many other available properties, but some fail including most importantly this one, with a method not supported error.  I know it is there, because I can use the command line tool to get it, but I can't figure out how to cleanly do it in VBS.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps you should post the vbs code that is failing, as well as the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to close this up, it had been a while since I've been on.  Basically it turned out that my query was good, but that the server I was interacting with had been improperly setup so there were a lot of inconsistencies resulting in what seemed like a coding error.  In the end, what was required was a shell out to the ldapsearch program, clunky, but functional.